# use reduce in typescript, Error "element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type can't be used to index type '{}'"

Tags: typescript

I get error:

> element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'POST_TYPE'
>   can't be used to index type '{}'
>   Property '[POST_TYPE.POST]' does not exist on type '{}';

error when using reduce on a function with an interface like this:

```
// enum
export const enum POST_TYPE {
  POST = 'POST',
  BOARD = 'BOARD',
  ...
}

// interface
export interface Post {
  postType?: POST_TYPE[];
}

export interface PostType {
  POST?: boolean;
  BOARD?: boolean;
}

// function
const exec = (prevType: Post['postType'], type: PostType) => {
 const prevObject = prevType.reduce((prev, it) => {
    prev[it] = true; -->> ERROR in prev[it]
    return prev;
  }, {});
}
```

What mistake did I make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue is that your argument `prevType: Post['postType']` may be `undefined`, because `Post['postType']` may be `undefined`. Not sure what you're trying to do there, but perhaps make the `postType` property required on `Post`, and type-check before passing the object to `exec`.

In your code, the second parameter passed to `reduce` lacks a type - it's just a plain object, and you didn't pass a type parameter to `.reduce`, so Typescript won't allow you to add arbitrary key-value pairs to it.

If you pass a type parameter to `reduce`, this will denote the type of the initial value and the accumulator. Here, because the type will be an object with partial properties of `POST_TYPE`, create such an object type and use `Partial`. Then you can assert that the return value is a full object (without missing properties):

```
export interface Post {
    postType: POST_TYPE[];
}
const exec = (prevType: Post['postType']) => {
    type PostObj = {
        [T in POST_TYPE]: boolean;
    };
    const prevObject = prevType.reduce<Partial<PostObj>>((prev, it) => {
        prev[it] = true;
        return prev;
    }, {}) as PostObj;
};
```

But `reduce` is a bit verbose and arguably [not the right tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnZ7jMFCa4Y) to use when creating a single object anyway. It might be more appropriate to just declare the object and assign to its properties, or to use `Object.fromEntries`:

```
const postObj = Object.fromEntries(
    prevType.map(it => [it, true])
) as PostObj;
```

(unfortunately, TS doesn't look to be able to infer the type of the return value of `fromEntries` sufficiently yet, thus the need for the type assertion)