# Why do I get "can't be used to index type '{}'" errors when using Reduce in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have written a function with the following interface:

```
enum DayOfWeek {
  MONDAY = 'monday',
  TUESDAY = 'tuesday',
  WEDNESDAY = 'wednesday',
  THURSDAY = 'thursday',
  FRIDAY = 'friday',
  SATURDAY = 'saturday',
  SUNDAY = 'sunday',
}

interface Daily {
  task: string | null;
  day: DayOfWeek;
}

interface NewDaily {
  task: string | null;
}

interface Post {
  ...
  schedule?: Daily[];
}

interface NewPost {
  ...
  schedule?: {
    monday?: NewDaily,
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a new object through a reduce function on the "schedule" of type Array passed in as an argument.

```
const exec = (schedule: Exclude<Post['schedule'], undefined>): NewPost['schedule'] => schedule.reduce((prev, it) => {
  prev[it.day] = {
    task: it.task; 
  }

  --> "prev[it]" occured :::: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'DayOfWeek' can't be used to index type '{}' Property '[DayOfWeek.MONDAY'] does not exist on type '{}'

  return prev;
}, {});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `it` is an object, not something that can be used as an object key - an object key must be a string or number (or Symbol), so `prev[it]` isn't permitted. (another issue is that the first parameter to `exec` may be `undefined`, so calling `reduce` on it isn't allowed)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ah! I just modified that code.

It is prev [it.day], not prev [it].

Excluded an issue where schedule could be undefined.

Comment: Looks to be exactly the same issue as in the prior question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60557834 - *the second parameter passed to reduce lacks a type - it's just a plain object, and you didn't pass a type parameter to .reduce, so Typescript won't allow you to add arbitrary key-value pairs to it*

Comment: Reduce take a type from neutral element you need to do `{} as WantedType`